# Si la matriz en c++ muestra un ciclo infinito, y no lo que se guardo, como puedo corregirlo?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Se trata de un programa que guarde el peso de 16 pacientes cuales asisten a 2 consultorios. Se debe de poder registrar peso, consultarlo y mostrar el peso de todos los pacientes. Sin embargo únicamente puede registrarlo.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    using namespace std;

    int menu(int ac);
    int registrar(float m[2][16]);
    int consultar(float m[2][16]);
     int reporte (float m[2][16]);
     int salir ();

   int ac;
   int main()
   {

         int x, repetir=1, opcion;
         float matriz[2][16];

         do
         {
            opcion=menu(ac);
            if (opcion==1)
            {
                cout<<"Registro de pacientes"<<endl;
                registrar(matriz);
            }
            else 
            {
                if (opcion==2)
                {
                    cout<<"Consulta de pacientes"<<endl;
                    consultar(matriz);
                }   
            else
            {
                 if(opcion==3)
                  {
                    cout<<"Modificacion de pacientes"<<endl;
                    
                    }
            else 
            {
                if(opcion==4)
                {
                    cout<<"Eliminacion de pacientes"<<endl;
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    if(opcion==5)
                    {
                        cout<<"Reporte de todos los pacientes"<<endl;
                        reporte (matriz);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(opcion<9||opcion>9)
                        {
                            cout<<"Opcion incorrecta"<<endl;
                        }   
                     }
                    }
                  } 
                }
            }
        }while(opcion<9||opcion>9);

        cout<<"Salida"<<endl;
       salir();

            getch();
             return 0;
            }

         int menu(int ac)                                                       
          //Se declara la función para el menu
        
          cout<<" ||    ACCIONES A REALIZAR:                            
       ||  "<<endl;
        cout<<" ||  [ 1 ] Registro de peso y sus pacientes            
         ||  "<<endl;
            cout<<" ||                                                    
        ||  "<<endl;
          cout<<" ||  [ 2 ] Consulta y busqueda de sus pacientes        
         ||  "<<endl;
   
            cout<<" ||  [ 3 ] Modificacion de pacientes                   
         ||  "<<endl;
               cout<<" ||               (En caso de que suban                
          ||  "<<endl;
           cout<<" ||                           O bajen de peso)                      
           ||  "<<endl;
            cout<<" ||  [ 4 ] Eliminar algun paciente                                  
       ||  "<<endl;
            cout<<" ||                    (Si dejaste de 
         trabajarle...)   ||  "<<endl;
            cout<<" ||  [ 5 ] Reporte de pacientes                        
       ||  "<<endl;
            cout<<" ||            (Aqui te encontraras con                
        ||  "<<endl;
            cout<<" ||                    La lista e informacion          
         ||  "<<endl;
            cout<<" ||                             De tus pacientes)      
       ||  "<<endl;
    cout<<" ||  [ 9 ] Salir                                       ||  
         "<<endl;
                   cout<<" ||          (O sea que se va... Se va y no 
          regresa)   ||  "<<endl;
            cout<<" ||                                                    
          ||  "<<endl;
           cout<<" || ¿Que deseas realizar?                              
          ||  "<<endl;
         cout<<" ||              ";
         cin>>ac;                                                                
       //Se lee ac
            cout<<" 
          ||____________________________________________________||  " 
         <<endl;
             cout<<" ||                                                    
         ||  "<<endl;  
              return ac;                                                     
                //Detiene la ejecucion de una funcion o devuelve un 
             valor
                 }

        int registrar (float m[2][16])
        {
            int paciente, repetir=0,consultorio;
            do
            {
                do
                {
                    cout<<"En que consultorio te encuentras?"<<endl;
                    cin>>consultorio;
                    if(consultorio<1||consultorio>2)
                    {
                    cout<<"Ese consultorio no existe"<<endl;
                    }
                    }while(consultorio<1||consultorio>2);
                    do
                    {
                    cout<<"Que paciente desea registrar?"<<endl;
                cin>>paciente;
                if (paciente<=0||paciente>16)
                {
                    cout<<"opcion incorrecta"<<endl;    
                }       
           }while (paciente<=0||paciente>16);
             do
                {
                cout<<"Peso? "<<endl;
            cin>>m[consultorio -1][paciente-1];
                    if (m[consultorio -1][paciente-1] 
       <1||m[consultorio -1][paciente-1]>200)
        {
            cout<<"Peso imposible para un ser humano"<<endl;
        }
    }while(m[consultorio -1][paciente-1]<1||m[consultorio -1] 
      [paciente-1]>200);
    cout<<"registrado" <<endl;
    cout<<"Repetir?? si=0"<<endl;
    cin>>repetir;


            
        }while(repetir==0);
        system("pause");
           system("cls");

        return 0();
           }

             int consultar(float m[2][16])
               {
            int paciente,consultorio, repetir=0;
                do
           {
            do
            {
        cout<<"En que consultorio se encuentra?"<<endl;
        cin>>consultorio;
        if(consultorio<1||consultorio>2)
        {
            cout<<"Has ingresado un numero incorrecto"<<endl;
        }
    }while( consultorio<=0 || consultorio>=3);
    do 
    {
        cout<<"Paciente"<<endl;
        cin>>paciente;
        if (paciente<1 || paciente>16)
        {
            cout<<"Este paciente no existe"<<endl;
        }
        }while(paciente<1 || paciente>16);
        cout<< m [consultorio-1][paciente-1];
        cout<<"Desea repetir? (presione 0 para repetir, y cualquier 
        otra tecla para no)"<<endl;
         cin>>repetir;
    

      }while(repetir==0);
        return main();
            }
      
             int reporte (float m[2][16])
        {
            int i,j,pacientes=16,consultorios=2;

        for(i=0;i=consultorios-1;i++)
         {
                for (j=0;j=pacientes-1;j++)
            {
            cout<<m[i][j];
            }
                cout<<"   "<<endl;
            }
              system("pause");
             system("cls");

            return 0;
             }

               int salir()
        {
          cout<<"Hasta pronto, dr..."<<endl;

        return 0;
       }
```

El algoritmo guarda la matriz, y regresa al menu, sin embargo al momento de consultar pone un numero que no es y en el reporte de los pacientes aparece el bucle infinito con muchos 0.

```
        for (int x=0;x=2;x++)
        {
            for (int y=0;y=16;y++)
            {
                matriz[x][y]=0.00;
            }
        }
```

He intentado agregando un valor inicial de 0 a la matriz y todos sus espacios, sin embargo cada que hago esto ni si quiera ejecuta, no muestra nada nada el programa y no responde a ninguna tecla...

Lo único que ejecuta bien es el registro y la salida.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Evita pedir las cosas urgentemente... Este es un sitio de personas que brindan su tiempo gratis, cuando pueden...

Answer (score 0):

En C++ las comparaciones se hacen con `==`, el operador `=` se usa únicamente para asignaciones.

Al confundir estos operadores permites que el bucle se convierta en un ciclo sin fín. Esto sucede porque el bucle for **siempre** va a comprobar, en cada iteración, si debe continuar o no.

Cuando pones una comparación explícita, pues como que queda claro cual es al condición que se va a evaluar, pero si te equivocas y pones una asignación ... ya no se ve tan claro.

Lo que sucede con las asignaciones es que se va a evaluar el valor asignado, si dicho valor es 0, entonces el bucle deja de iterar. Entonces, si en el condicional del `for` pones `x=2`, como nunca asignas un 0, el bucle se repetirá indefinidamente.

Así que tu código debería estar así:

```
for (int x=0;x==2;x++)
//            ^^ comparación
{
    for (int y=0;y==16;y++)
    //            ^^ comparación
    {
        matriz[x][y]=0.00;
    }
}
```

Lo que sucede ahora es que, de repente, los bucles ya no iteran. Esto sucede porque las condiciones de los mismos no son correctas. En este caso tendrías que usar el operador `<`, ya que los bucles se deberían repetir hasta que se alcancen las dimensiones del array:

```
for (int x=0;x<2;x++)
{
    for (int y=0;y<16;y++)
    {
        matriz[x][y]=0.00;
    }
}
```

Y con esto ya lo tendrías.

Te podría haber respondido directamente, pero creo que así es más ilustrativo